# LiveData not captured when unit testing Either.fold()

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk, arrow-kt

I'm trying to add unit tests to a project that we've inherited from another company, but I can't manage to make them work since I'm not very experienced with testing and I never used the Arrow-kt library.

The function `GetAEQueries.Params.forAEQueryRequest(queryRequest)` returns an `Either<Failure, List<AEQuery>>`

They use the following architecture for Viewmodels:

```
    private var _queryList = MutableLiveData<Result<List<AEQuery>>>()
    val queryList: LiveData<Result<List<AEQuery>>> get() = _queryList    

    fun foo(queryRequest: AEQueryRequest, consultationType: ConsultationType) {
        _lastFilter.postValue(queryRequest)
        _queryList.postValue(Result.Loading())
        launch {
            getAEQueries(GetAEQueries.Params.forAEQueryRequest(queryRequest)).fold(
                {
                    // Failure
                    _queryList.postValue(Result.Error(it))
             
                },
                { queries ->
                    // Success
                    _queryList.postValue(Result.Success(queries))
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

And this is the test I'm trying to run

```
    @get:Rule
    val instantRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)

        viewModel = ConsultationsListViewModel(
            testDispatcher,
            appNavigator,
            transactionsNavigator,
            dialogNavigator,
            getAEQueries,
            getAEServices,
            getAEDownload
        )
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    @Test
    fun `requestToGetAEQueries OK should update queryList with the result`() = runTest {
        // Given
        val queryRequest = // Mocked request
        val consultationType = // Mocked consultation type
        val expectedQueries = // Mocked return
        val expectedResult: Either<Failure, List<AEQuery>> = expectedQueries.right()

        coEvery { getAEQueries(GetAEQueries.Params.forAEQueryRequest(queryRequest)) } returns expectedResult

        // When
        viewModel.requestToGetAEQueries(queryRequest, consultationType)

        // Then
        viewModel.lastFilter.observeOnce {
            assert(it == queryRequest)
        }
        viewModel.queryList.observeOnce {
            if(it is Result.Loading) {
                assert(it == Result.Loading(null))
            } else if (it is Result.Success) {
                assert(it == Result.Success(expectedQueries))
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem that I've got here is that the test captures the `lastFilter` LiveData correctly, but doesn't capture anything inside the viewmodel's `.fold()` function so it never reaches the Result.Success condition.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is observeOnce? Does it work the way it named? So does it really get to "else if" block if queryList has "Loading" in the first place? Also it's strange to have if/else block in "one state" test: it will be either Loading or Result

Comment: ObserveOnce is not the problem here (maybe in the future), I found out that using mockk I must create capturers for the lambdas that the fold() function takes as arguments, but I still didn't manage to make it work, check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75931492/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-when-trying-to-capture-lambdas-in-unit-test-using

Comment: "using mockk I must create capturers for the lambdas that the fold() function takes as arguments" what for? Somehow it sounds like overthinking, because lastFilter works (as you mention in question)

Comment: As I explained in the question, the lastFilter LiveData is reached. For testing purposes I've put it inside both .fold() lambdas along the Result.Loading LiveData and neither of them gets called, so that's how I found out about the capturers

Comment: OK. I don't know what your "observeOnce" consists of, so I made look a like funs (with `Either` and `fold`) and test using `mockk`, but I used `liveData.value`:
 `(viewModel.queryList.value as? Result.Success)?.let { assertTrue(it.queries == expectedQueries) }` and `assertTrue(viewModel.lastFilter.value == queryRequest)`

It works.